# Lost printing routine

Tags: windows-8.1, printing, toshiba-laptop

8.1 on Toshiba Satellite 50B:  Lost printing ability.  After clicking"Print" nothing. Doc doesn't appear in "Docs in Queue" or "printing" or anywhere else.  This includes "Print test page".

Comment: @danielpopa  Thanks,but no joy.  Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/946737?wa=wsignin1.0

To clear your queue or any other hanged jobs, try this:

1. Enter in (Admin) Command Prompt, type: `Net Stop Spooler`, this will close print services.
2. Then type: `del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q`, this will delete anything that you have in pool.
3. Then type: `Net Start Spooler`, and start printing service.